# Hide cells depending on select value - generated HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem writing a function to hide two cells depending on the selected value.
The biggest problem is that the **HTML is generated and there can be one such select or eight of them**. And to make things more interesting, every one of this select is placed in a separate div and while one is shown, others are hidden.

Here is the function I use to toggle cells. Cells can be shown only if selected value is 'Z', otherwise they must be hidden. It works only on the first select while other are completely ignored. I was trying to use `.each()` function for every element with `id="selector"` but there was quite a mass with element indexes and it didn't work either.

```
$("#selector").change(function(){
  if($(this).val().trim() == 'Z'){
      $("#labelToHide").toggle(true);
      $("#selectToHide").toggle(true);
  } else {
      $("#labelToHide").toggle(false);
      $("#selectToHide").toggle(false);
  }
});
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bH7tx/2/). It might look incomplete, but it is enough to simulate real situation. Bellow is the XML code I work with from which the HTML is generated.

```
<xh:td class="RightColumn" id="selectToHide">
    <form:selectOne ...>
        <!-- form code -->
    </form:selectOne>
</xh:td>
```

Is there some way I can make this script work only for currently shown div? Or is there some other workaround?

Comment: First thing first, you can't use the same ID as you will only ever select the first one.  IDs *must* be unique.  Give them a class instead.

Comment: Thanks. I added the code from which HTML is generated. I'm going to try that with classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the multiple use of IDs it was never going to work as you were doing it.  In the following I've changed all the IDs to relevant classes and modified the script to take that into account...

**HTML**

```
<div id="divOne">
    <table class="gridtable">
        <tr>
            <td id="allwaysShown">Allways Shown</td>
            <td id="allwaysShown">
                <select class="selector">
                    <option value="Z">Z</option>
                    <option value="X">X</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="toHide">Hide this</td>
            <td class="toHide">
                <select>
                    <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                    <option value="N">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="divTwo">
    <table class="gridtable">
        <tr>
            <td id="allwaysShown">Allways Shown</td>
            <td id="allwaysShown">
                <select class="selector">
                    <option value="Z">Z</option>
                    <option value="X">X</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="toHide">Hide this</td>
            <td class="toHide">
                <select>
                    <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                    <option value="N">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".selector").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim() == 'Z') {
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".toHide").show();
    } else {
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".toHide").hide();
    }
});
```

What this now does is when a select element (with the class `selector`) changes, it parses up the DOM to find the row that it is contained in, and then finds all the elements with the class `toHide`, and either hides or shows them.

[**Your jsfiddle, modified...**](http://jsfiddle.net/bH7tx/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Once you fix the issue with multiple `id` by changing them to `class`, you can use the following :

```
$(".selector").change(function () {
 if ($(this).val().trim() == 'Z') {
    $(this).parent().nextAll("td").show();
 } else {
    $(this).parent().nextAll("td").hide();
 }
});

$(".selectToHide select").change(function () {
 if ($(this).val().trim() == 'Y') {
    $(this).parent('td').prev().show();
 } else {
    $(this).parent('td').prev().hide();
 }
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bH7tx/11/)

Comment: when I clicked it, my original fiddle was shown. But it works now

Comment: @dallows ok.. i must've pasted the link from wrong tab -_-

Answer (score 1):

**You must use unique ids**, use `classes` instead of ids to group the elements. Instead of toggle use show / hide and assign common class to both select and label e.g. toShowHide and use single call to show hide both. I have changed the html attributes just to demonstrate you should change according to your requirement by keeping in mind that ids must be unique.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bH7tx/13/)**

```
$(".selector").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim() == 'Z') 
        $(this).parent().siblings(".toShowHide").show();        
     else 
        $(this).parent().siblings(".toShowHide").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML id's are all unique, that means on a single page of HTML there can only be one id with the same name, if you have used #selector before, you shouldn't use it again (it won't work in the first place.)

Always use a class for this.

Here's [**your working code**](http://jsfiddle.net/awesomestvi/e46rL/) as you needed it

```
    <div id="divOne">
        <table class="gridtable">
            <tr>
                <td class="allwaysShown">Allways Shown</td>
                <td class="allwaysShown">
                    <select class="selector">
                        <option value="Z">Z</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="hide_this">Hide this</td>
                <td class="hide_this">
                    <select>
                        <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                        <option value="N">No</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="divTwo">
        <table class="gridtable">
            <tr>
                <td class="allwaysShown">Allways Shown</td>
                <td class="allwaysShown">
                    <select class="selector">
                        <option value="Z">Z</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="hide_this">Hide this</td>
                <td class="hide_this">
                    <select>
                        <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                        <option value="N">No</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
    $(".selector").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val().trim() == 'Z') {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.hide_this').show();
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.hide_this').hide();
        }
    });
```